# How to put a number inside the symbol as shown

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols, scientific-notation, tikzsymbols

I wanted to put the numbers or texts inside a mathematical symbol as shown in the picture. I am sorry, that I do not know the name of this particular mathematical symbol. Please guide me type the following notation in latex.[image]

Comment: Do you really need the whole image? Crop it keeping necessary portion only.

Comment: @mmr I need only the notation inscribing the number

Comment: What is it used for? @gete

Comment: In Horner's method of division algorithm of polynomial, we use thise notation to imply the remainder.

Comment: The `polynom` package supports typesetting polynomial long division using the Horner Schema. You should look into its manual to see the use.

Comment: @WillieWong May it `polynom` package's `\polyhornerscheme` needs extra params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems not a conventional symbol, you can make a macro for using it. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\horner}[1]{%
  \begin{array}{@{\vline}l}\,#1\,\\\hline\end{array}
}

\begin{document}
Text

$\horner{866}$

Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I read it as factorial of 866, $866!$. But then I read old-fashioned algebra books. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724454/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-symbol-left-underline-n-right-for-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a closer symbol from `steinmetz` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{steinmetz}

\begin{document}
$\phase{866}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

or you can use `esrelation` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{esrelation}

\begin{document}
$\relationlifting{866}$

\end{document}
```

[image]